# Problem in changing values from a row in a matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I'm working on a code that on a certain point fills a 2x9 matrix with values (the matrix is, as default, filled with `None` values).

```
for i in range(1, 9):
    memoria_cache[0][i] = ram[int(bintodec(cache[0] + cache[1] + dectobin(i-1, 3)))]
    print(memoria_cache)
```

The code is supposed to only iterate through the first row, but in the output it changes both rows at once instead. Could someone shed a light on this matter?

Comment: You probably used `memoria_cache = [[0]*9]*2`.  That creates ONE 9-entry list, and makes two references to that same list.  Changing either reference changes the list object, and is seen in both places.

Comment: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178) possibly.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (MRE) that includes initializing the matrix.